# How can I block ssh in oracle cloud?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to permit ssh connection only to specific ip range. But I couldn't find the firewall setting in web console, so I tried `ufw`.

First I tried blocking specific ip for test, but ssh connection wasn't blocked. The following is  diagnostic information. How can I make the first rule of ufw work?

```
➜  ~ sudo ufw status verbose                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <<<
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   DENY IN     x.x.x.x
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
➜  ~ ss
Netid    State         Recv-Q    Send-Q                      Local Address:Port                 Peer Address:Port      Process
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 21064                           * 21065
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 22634                           * 22683
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 128716                          * 128717
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/dbus/system_bus_socket 22683                           * 22634
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 128684                          * 128688
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/dbus/system_bus_socket 22681                           * 20730
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 21065                           * 21064
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/dbus/system_bus_socket 128717                          * 128716
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 21293                           * 19446
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 20731                           * 20732
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 20732                           * 20731
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 22275                           * 22274
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 128688                          * 128684
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                    //tmp/plugin1uab6tlg 24325                           * 24768
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 22693                           * 22694
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 22884                           * 22883
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 22652                           * 22684
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 21376                           * 19449
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/dbus/system_bus_socket 22684                           * 22652
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 19285                           * 22678
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 22694                           * 22693
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 22883                           * 22884
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 21453                           * 19453
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 24768                           * 24325
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/dbus/system_bus_socket 22678                           * 19285
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 19453                           * 21453
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 19446                           * 21293
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 19449                           * 21376
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/dbus/system_bus_socket 22908                           * 22907
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 22912                           * 22913
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 22677                           * 22676
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 20754                           * 22682
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/dbus/system_bus_socket 22682                           * 20754
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 22676                           * 22677
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 22907                           * 22908
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 22913                           * 22912
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 20314                           * 19017
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 129399                          * 129398
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 20988                           * 19439
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 20661                           * 19357
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 20206                           * 20208
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 129277                          * 0
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 18773                           * 18766
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 16574                           * 16565
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 22274                           * 22275
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 19017                           * 20314
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 21865                           * 21864
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 20208                           * 20206
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 129398                          * 129399
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 19510                           * 18771
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 19357                           * 20661
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 20571                           * 22680
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 20570                           * 22679
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 18771                           * 19510
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/systemd/journal/stdout 21658                           * 21653
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 18766                           * 18773
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 21864                           * 21865
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 19439                           * 20988
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/dbus/system_bus_socket 22679                           * 20570
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 20730                           * 22681
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 21653                           * 21658
u_str    ESTAB         0         0             /run/dbus/system_bus_socket 22680                           * 20571
u_str    ESTAB         0         0                                       * 16565                           * 16574
icmp6    UNCONN        0         0                                  *%ens3:ipv6-icmp                       *:*
tcp      CLOSE-WAIT    1         0                                10.0.0.3:49906             169.254.169.254:http
tcp      ESTAB         0         148                              10.0.0.3:ssh                x.x.x.x:55290
tcp      CLOSE-WAIT    1         0                                10.0.0.3:49358             169.254.169.254:http
tcp      CLOSE-WAIT    32        0                                10.0.0.3:55582              140.204.24.145:https
tcp      CLOSE-WAIT    1         0                                10.0.0.3:49360             169.254.169.254:http
tcp      CLOSE-WAIT    32        0                                10.0.0.3:56130              140.204.24.145:https
tcp      CLOSE-WAIT    1         0                                10.0.0.3:49908             169.254.169.254:http
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the web console, Hamburger -> Networking -> Virtual Cloud Networks -> click VCN to edit -> Security lists (on the left), edit Ingress rules.